# How can I access the leaf node of the JSON file to retrieve the sales_value of the year 2022 for all customers, and then sum them up in Python?

Tags: python, json

`{ "customer_data": [ { "name": "John Smith", "age": 35, "email": "johnsmith@gmail.com", "phone": "0413-535-124", "sales_value": [ { "year": "2022", "sales_value": 2000 }, { "year": "2023", "sales_value": 3000 } ] }, { "name": "Jane Doe", "age": 28, "email": "janedoe@yahoo.com", "phone": "0401-655-568", "sales_value": [ { "year": "2022", "sales_value": 2000 }, { "year": "2023", "sales_value": 3000 } ] }, { "name": "Bob Johnson", "age": 42, "email": "bjohnson@hotmail.com", "phone": "0433-515-912", "sales_value": [ { "year": "2022", "sales_value": 2000 }, { "year": "2023", "sales_value": 3000 } ] }, { "name": "Bob2 Johnson", "age": 42, "email": "bjohnson@hotmail.com", "phone": "0433-515-912", "sales_value": [ { "year": "2022", "sales_value": 2000 }, { "year": "2023", "sales_value": 3000 } ] }, { "name": "Bob3 Johnson", "age": 42, "email": "bjohnson@hotmail.com", "phone": "0433-515-912", "sales_value": [ { "year": "2022", "sales_value": 2000 }, { "year": "2023", "sales_value": 3000 } ] } ] }`

Using above json file needs to calculate sales_value of the year 2022 in python.
Pls can you guide me how to get leaf node and calculate total sales value of 2022

I have tried to get leaf node

Comment: Moderators at strike https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an - so I also will not do **any** (further) content/curation-related action here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're certain that the json would contain the 'sales_value' field for each customer, then you can try the follwing, which should be self explanatory:

```
import json
with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
total_sales_value = 0
for customer in data['customer_data']:
    for sales in customer['sales_value']:
        if sales['year']=='2022':
            total_sales_value += sales['sales_value']
```

As for less readable one liner:

```
sum([sales['sales_value'] for customer in data['customer_data'] for sales in customer['sales_value'] if sales['year']=='2022'])
```

Output:

```
10000
```